# How do I work out the number of variations of 5 letters of the alphabet?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm running a program at the moment that runs through every variation of 5 letters that can be found in the alphabet. How can I calculate how many variations this amounts to?

I'm guessing it is less than every variation in the ordering of the alphabet (i.e 26!) and is obviously more than 5!, but I have no idea how to calculate exactly how many it will be. Pointing me in the direction of any books/articles that would help me work this sort of thing out in the future would also be great.

I realise this is probably fairly straightforward for many of you, but any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Do you mean how many ways can you order 5 letters of the alphabet without replacement? If so, you have 26 choices for the first one, 25 for the next, 24 for the third, and so on.

Comment: if you're interested in the number of distinct ways of writing down 5 letters in a row with replacement, think about in base 10, how many ways there are of writing an $n$ digit number. With letters, you are in base 26...

Comment: Yes sorry with no repetitions - so a,a,c,d,e is not allowed.  So the amount would be 26*25*24*23*22, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on whether you count strings of 5 letters with repetition of letters allowed, or strings where repetition of letters is not allowed (e.g., does "abaca" count, where $a$ appears three times?)

It also depends on whether permutations of the same five letters count as separate variations. E.g., are "abcde" and "edcba" both count? If they both count count, we'll call each of these distinct strings.

Assuming repetition doesn't count, and that we're looking at distinct strings, then we have the following number of distinct strings that can be constructed with 5 of 26 letters: $$26\times 25\times 24\times 23\times 22 = 7893600$$

If repetition of letters is allowed, then we have the following number of distinct strings: $$26\times 26\times 26\times 26\times 26 = 26^5 = 11881376$$

Comment: Yes, with no repetitions allowed, and distinct strings. That's exactly what I was looking for thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first letter can be one of a-z, so can the second, the third etc. Therefore there are $26^5$ combinations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I should have specified with no repetitions. I would give you a +1 but I don't have enough reputation on this version of stack exchange yet.

Comment: Well, I would edit my answer then, but as there is already a correct one, I won‘t.